# Automatic email trigger on uploading a file in a folder

Tags: html

I have my html webpage like this [home](http://mukherjee.web.elte.hu/plots_charge_cloud/). I want to automatically send an email which contains the file link whenever I upload a new file to any of the folders as given in the location above. My webpage is written completely in html without any javascript or php.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I am a beginner in HTML coding and don't know much. I want to know how to get it done.